# Do we read ''t'' sound in spoken English?

Tags: pronunciation, british-english, spoken-english, glottal-stop

Here are some examples;

> He looked at me

> He looked a(**t**) me

or

> He went out a second ago.

> He went ou(**t**) a second ago.

Do we read ''t'' sound in spoken English?

Comment: You need [T-glottalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-glottalization).

Comment: Great! That's what I mean: T-glottalization

Comment: I've posted another [related question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/150711/glottalizations).

Comment: Are you asking about UK English or American English?

Comment: Why wouldn't we?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "t" is pronounced, but somewhat softly; in both "at" and "out" the emphasis is on the vowel leading the word. As one of the comments pointed out, the exact pronunciation differs drastically by region and accent. (In California we tend to somewhat slur words beginning with vowels.)
If in doubt, enunciate and pronounce the "t" clearly.